# How to change the duration of user access?

Tags: 7, cookies

By default Drupal keeps users logged in 2.000000 seconds, i modify in settings.php at the line:

```
ini_set('session_cookie_lifetime',2000000);
```

It is right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are correct. Changing these settings will change the session time for logged in users.